# Altair - Gradient above line

Tags: altair

I want to create an area chart, however the gradient should run from the line up to the top of the chart. Any ideas?

example of a regular gradient chart here https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/area_chart_gradient.html

```
alt.Chart(source).transform_filter(
    'datum.symbol==="GOOG"'
).mark_area(
    line={'color':'darkgreen'},
    color=alt.Gradient(
        gradient='linear',
        stops=[alt.GradientStop(color='white', offset=0),
               alt.GradientStop(color='darkgreen', offset=1)],
        x1=1,
        x2=1,
        y1=1,
        y2=0
    )
).encode(
    alt.X('date:T'),
    alt.Y('price:Q')
)
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `y2` encoding to `alt.value(0)` – the zero in this case measures pixels from the top of the chart axis:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

alt.Chart(source).transform_filter(
    'datum.symbol==="GOOG"'
).mark_area(
    line={'color':'darkgreen'},
    color=alt.Gradient(
        gradient='linear',
        stops=[alt.GradientStop(color='white', offset=0),
               alt.GradientStop(color='darkgreen', offset=1)],
        x1=1,
        x2=1,
        y1=1,
        y2=0
    )
).encode(
    alt.X('date:T'),
    alt.Y('price:Q'),
    y2=alt.value(0)
)
```

[image]